# anyone please write XSLT code for this xml?

Tags: xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school>
<classes>
    <class>
        <name>DEPT-NAME</name>
        <place>ROOM-NO</place>
    </class>
</classes>
<alldata>
    <data>
        <value>CSE</value>
        <value>101</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <value>IT</value>
        <value>202</value>
    </data>
</alldata>
<students>
    <student>
        <DEPT-NAME>CSE</DEPT-NAME>
        <name>Jhon</name>
        <roll>111</roll>
    </student>
    <student>
        <DEPT-NAME>CSE</DEPT-NAME>
        <name>Zubi</name>
        <roll>112</roll>
    </student>
    <student>
        <DEPT-NAME>IT</DEPT-NAME>
        <name>Jack</name>
        <roll>121</roll>
    </student>
    <student>
        <DEPT-NAME>IT</DEPT-NAME>
        <name>Razz</name>
        <roll>122</roll>
    </student>
</students>
</school>
```

I want a csv output like

1. DEPT-NAME  ROOM-NO   NAME ROLLNO
2. CSE         101      Jhon  111
3. __*_*__*_*____Zubi  112
4. IT          202      Jack  121
5. __*_*__*_*____Razz  122

I was trying to do like this way but it did't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>SCHOOL</xsl:text>

        <xsl:variable name="StudentCSE">
            <xsl:for-each select="school/students/student[DEPT-NAME='CSE']">
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="roll"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="Value">
        <xsl:for-each select="school/alldata/data">
                    <xsl:text>&#010;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:for-each select="value" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$StudentCSE"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:for-each select="school/classes/class">
                <xsl:text>&#010;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="place"/><xsl:text>,NAME,ROll</xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$Value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Q1: How are you trying to convert the file?  What program are you using?   Q2: Did you get any errors or warnings?  Q3: What, exactly, "isn't working"?  Please clarify.

Comment: I was trying to convert xml to csv file, No error is there but I can't retrieve the data in formatted way..
I am getting output like..
DEPT-NAME ROOM-NO NAME ROLL
CSE   101  Jhon 111 Zubi 112
IT    202  Jhon 111 Zubi 112

Comment: I think you should use a service like Amazon Turk for this. Voting to close.

Comment: probably a poorly worded title; but certainly a new genuine issue.  the challenge is @Sndy trying to "join" using xpath with a predicate.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to reformat because I removed many of your  elements for simplicity, but to solve your issue, try a <xsl:key> to create a classroom lookup.

The <xsl:key> let's us create a hashmap/dictionary using the data node as payload and the content of data's first value element as the key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:key name="class-lookup" match="school/alldata/data" use="value[1]" />

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <!-- header -->
      <xsl:for-each select="school/classes/class">
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="place"/>, NAME, ROll
      </xsl:for-each>

      <!-- data -->
      <xsl:for-each select="school/students/*">
         <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="DEPT-NAME"/>, <xsl:value-of select="key('class-lookup', DEPT-NAME)/value[2]" />, <xsl:value-of select="name"/>,  <xsl:value-of select="roll"/>
      </xsl:for-each>

   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
DEPT-NAME, ROOM-NO, NAME, ROll

CSE, 101, Jhon,  111
CSE, 101, Zubi,  112
IT, 202, Jack,  121
IT, 202, Razz,  122
```

Comment: Thank you vary much. It showing CSE/IT two times,but that is fine. I got The output.